# What drives hits to this site?

Tags: discussion, views

Can anyone please explain how come [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/free-as-in-free-speech-not-as-in-free-beer) got 1k views in nine hours?

Not that I object. :) Just trying to understand what drives hits to this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is featured in the "hot questions" in the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™:

[image]

Of course for a question to make it into that list, it first has to get a few upvotes in a short time (more details on the "hot questions" algorithm [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)), and yours did (it's a good question, after all). So a lot of the traffic came from within the Stack Exchange network.

Also, a chunk of the traffic probably came from [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), as the question was [featured in our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8116310#8116310). That's how I found out about it.

Comment: Make sense, I've seen it on SE questions page. The question is, how did it get there?

Comment: @bytebuster You got a lot of upvotes in a short time, see the link in my answer for a fuller explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: Do you mean, it triggers SE to pump it to the "popular" page, regardless of actual number of views? If so, it explains the thing.

Comment: @bytebuster `( (log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores) ) / ( ((Qage+1) - ((Qage - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5 )`  Variables that factor in: Question views, age and score,  and answers score. The quick and good answers also played a big part in getting the question into the "hot" list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess this formula should be part of your answer.

Comment: It _is_ in the answer – sort of. One just needs to follow the [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions). :^)

Comment: Thank you for using the correct terminology to describe the *Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™*, and freehand circle :)